# Message sent over socket missing the \n

Tags: python, matlab, sockets

I am generating a protocol for a tcpip socket between python and matlab. While trying to setup some sort of a protocol, I ran into a problem. It has to do with this set of code below

```
FPath = Path('c:/test/dogg.jpg')     
HASH = Commons.get_file_md5_hash((FPath))

msg = ('IDINFO'+FPath.name+'HASH'+ HASH+'\n')
```

generates the message

```
IDINFOdogg.jpgHASH7ad1a930dab3c099939b66267b5c57f8
```

I have in the message: `IDINFO` which will tell the server the name of the file and `HASH` which will tell the file details.

After this I open up the file using

```
f = open(FPath,"rb")
chunk = f.read(1020)
```

and build a package with the tag `DATA` in front

```
msg = b`DATA` + chunk + b'\n'
```

Problem is that the `b'\n'` is not the same as in the first message. as Matlab cannot read the delimiter and won't continue grabbing data chunks.

Matlab code for Below reference. This isn't the entire object just the part that is potentially causing trouble. 
To setup a callback.

```
       set(gh.tcpipServer, 'BytesAvailableFcnMode','Terminator');
       set(gh.tcpipServer, 'BytesAvailableFcn', @(h,e)gh.Serverpull(h,e));
```

The Function for looking at the bytes

```
    function Serverpull(gh,h,e)
        gh.msg = fread(gh.tcpipServer,gh.tcpipServer.BytesAvailable);
        gh.msgdecode = char(transpose(gh.msg));

        if strfind(gh.msgdecode,'IDINFO')
            Hst = strfind(gh.msgdecode,'HASH');
            gh.Fname = gh.msgdecode(7:Hst-1);
            gh.HASH = gh.msgdecode(Hst+4:end);
            fwrite(gh.tcpipServer,'GoodToGo');

            gh.PrepareforDataAq()
        elseif strfind(gh.msgdecode,'DATA')
            fwrite(gh.fileID,gh.msg(5:end),'double');
        elseif strfind(gh.msgdecode,'EOF')
            fclose(gh.fileID);
            display('File Transfer Complete')
        end
    end
    function PrepareforDataAq(gh)
        path = fullfile('c:\temp\',gh.Fname);
        gh.fileID = fopen(path,'w');

    end
```

For the TLDR,

How to make the string `'\n'` the same as `b \n` when building a tcp message from binary instead of strings before encoding?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `b'\n'` by a plain `10`? BTW, you can't use a callback triggered by terminator detection if you are passing arbitrary binary data, unless you add in the protocol a specific mechanism to escape binary values equal to 10 (ASCII value for \n) or make sure there is not any, e.g. convert to hex representation or base64. Otherwise, `tcpip` object will detect any of these bytes as an end of message. Otherwise, `udp` has a `DatagramReceivedFcn` callback better suited for that (triggered on datagram reception rather than number of bytes or terminator).

Comment: IC, Thanks for the info. I shall set it to detect by Bytes then. I can send Byte size in the initial message and have matlab count down. Hopefully that way it won't hang on the last few bytes.

Comment: Well that failed. apperently matlab won't let you set the `BytesAvailableFcnMode` while the connection is open. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: You always have the option of reading all data coming, store it in an internal buffer then process the buffer. Like, each time n bytes are received, read the object buffer and concatenate it into a `Buffer` variable, then parse messages in the buffer variable (which may now be mixed text/binary: if you read `IDINFO` look for a \n terminator, if you read `DATA0123` take another 123 bytes). You still have to deal with the case where the transferred file contains some of the reserved keywords (like, try to transfer a txt file documenting the protocol messages)